# Magento 2: Send email based on timezone selected by customer

Tags: magento2, email, cron, date, timezone

I am developing extension in which I need to send email on base of selected Timezone by the customer.

I have set a cron which is working fine, however, I confused about to send email on the base of Timezone.

Could you help me to achieve this?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: are you need to use customer-selected timezone for changing sending time or for generate email content?

Comment: Yes Max, i need to send email on customer selected timezone.

Comment: Is my example expected behaviour? customer1 (timezone = UTC+1) => send email at 10am; customer2(timezone = UTC+2) => send email at 11am;

Comment: Thanks Max, it's matches some what. However, i need to send email on dynamic timezone. Actually, i am working on gift card extension on which customer must be able to select time zone so they can get gift card on desire time.